# mysql query optimization and manipulation of field value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
mysql> select * from dts;
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Id | key1 | key2 | serial | pr1  | pr2  | pr3  | pr4  | pr5  |
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |      1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    2 |
|  2 |    1 |    1 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  3 |    1 |    1 |      3 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|  4 |    1 |    1 |      4 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    3 |
|  5 |    1 |    2 |      5 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    2 |    5 |
|  6 |    1 |    2 |      6 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
|  7 |    1 |    2 |      7 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|  8 |    2 |    2 |      1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    2 |
|  9 |    2 |    2 |      2 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 10 |    3 |    2 |      3 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 11 |    3 |    3 |      1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |
| 12 |    3 |    3 |      5 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |
+----+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Logic I want to implement here is as follows**

> 1. check is there any non zero data in fields(pr1-pr5) of table dts ?
> 2. If found concat field name with comma, suppose if all fields are non zero, just concat fields and stop reading records of same key
>      (combination of key1,key2 to save execution time, look it 8th row in
>      above table for key1=2 and key2=2 all are non zero, so stop reading
>      next record with same keys), go to next key1,key2

**What is not working is as follows**

> At present code which I am using is working, but its not skipping
>   reading row when enough fields are found, as you can see for current
>   example it creates 12 rows X 5 Col = 60 Rows (if you execute inner
>   select statement it returns 60 rows) and then groups it by key1 and
>   key2, can it be done in any simple way which is efficient too so that
>   table with 2-3 million records will be faster.

**Expected output**

```
+------+------+---------------------+
| key1 | key2 | prs                 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|    1 |    1 | pr1,pr3,pr4,pr5     |
|    1 |    2 | pr2,pr4,pr5         |
|    2 |    2 | pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5 |
|    3 |    2 | NULL                |
|    3 |    3 | pr1,pr2,pr3,pr4,pr5 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

**So how this can be simplified to improve performance with large table, as you can see above my intention is simple, I just want to see how many fields (pr1-pr5) exists with non zero value for each combinations of key1, key2**

**Code am using**

```
SELECT 
    key1,
    key2,
    group_concat(distinct case when val > 0 then pr end order by pr separator ',') prs
FROM (
    SELECT 
        d.key1,
            d.key2,
            t.pr,
            CASE t.pr
                WHEN 'pr1' THEN pr1
                WHEN 'pr2' THEN pr2
                WHEN 'pr3' THEN pr3
                WHEN 'pr4' THEN pr4
                WHEN 'pr5' THEN pr5
            END val
    FROM
        dts d
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 'pr1' pr UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'pr2' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'pr3' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'pr4' UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'pr5'
    ) t
) r
GROUP BY key1 , key2;
```

**Structure**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dts`;
CREATE TABLE `dts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `key2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `serial` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr3` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr4` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `pr5` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `main` (`key1`,`key2`,`serial`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `dts` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `dts` VALUES (1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,2),(2,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0),(3,1,1,3,0,0,0,1,0),(4,1,1,4,1,0,1,1,3),(5,1,2,5,0,0,0,2,5),(6,1,2,6,0,0,0,0,1),(7,1,2,7,0,1,0,0,0),(8,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2),(9,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0),(10,3,2,3,0,0,0,0,0),(11,3,3,1,1,1,0,0,1),(12,3,3,5,0,0,1,1,0);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT key1, key2,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
         IF(pr1=0, NULL, 'pr1'),
         IF(pr2=0, NULL, 'pr2'),
         IF(pr3=0, NULL, 'pr3'),
         IF(pr4=0, NULL, 'pr4'),
         IF(pr5=0, NULL, 'pr5') ) AS prs
    FROM (
           SELECT key1, key2,
               SUM(pr1) AS pr1,
               SUM(pr2) AS pr2,
               SUM(pr3) AS pr3,
               SUM(pr4) AS pr4,
               SUM(pr5) AS pr5
            FROM dts
            GROUP BY key1, key2
         ) AS sums;
```

If you need "NULL" in the 3,2 row, you can add an `IFNULL` to fix it.

Comment: can't this be just  `SELECT key1, key2,
               CONCAT_WS(',', IF(SUM(pr1),'pr1',NULL),
               IF(SUM(pr2),'pr2',NULL),
               IF(SUM(pr3),'pr3',NULL),
               IF(SUM(pr4),'pr4',NULL),
               IF(SUM(pr5),'pr5',NULL)  ) AS prs
            FROM dts
            GROUP BY key1, key2` or will it create any problem if I do like this

Comment: @user3637224 - Looks correct and not-a-problem.  Post that as an answer and take the "best answer" away from me.